# Auto completion not working with driver object when using pytest fixture in another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pytest

I have a selenium python project with folder structure as

ProjectName
--fixturedemo
----conftest.py
----base_test.py

conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture
def getDriver(request, getBrowser):
    _driver = None
    if getBrowser == "chrome":
        _driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/myUser/sel/chromedriver")
    elif getBrowser == "firefox":
        pass
    request.cls.driver = _driver
    yield request.cls.driver
    time.sleep(2)
    request.cls.driver.quit()
```

Now this above **getDriver** fixture, I am using in another py file base_test.py as

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("getDriver")
class BaseTest:

    def open(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)
```

When I am typing dot after self.driver as `self.driver.`
I am not getting all available driver exposed methods or properties. how to solve this issue?
Basically how to get autosuggestions for the driver object?

Comment: this has nothing to do with pytest or any framework but the IDE that you are working with

Comment: When I am inheriting any class, the objects of parent class shows correct exposed methods, but with fixtures, driver object not exposing methods..as you are saying if it's an ide issue, what's the solution?